# How can I get my T450s laptop to use both its batteries?

Tags: laptop, power-management, hardware, battery

The Thinkpad T450s has dual batteries. My system (16.04) sees both of them, but here's the output of `acpi -V`:

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 0%
Battery 1: Discharging, 11%, 00:10:12 remaining
Battery 1: design capacity 2177 mAh, last full capacity 1938 mAh = 89%
```

So, it knows there are two. Strangely, `upower -i` has the numbers backwards (BAT0 seems known, BAT1 seems unknown). Here's the output of `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SONY
  model:                45N1111
  serial:               14929
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 08 Oct 2016 01:30:27 PM PDT (17 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       low
    energy:              1.65 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         20.66 Wh
    energy-full-design:  23.2 Wh
    energy-rate:         12.614 W
    voltage:             10.583 V
    time to empty:       7.8 minutes
    percentage:          7%
    capacity:            89.0517%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1475958627  7.000   discharging
    1475958537  8.000   discharging
  History (rate):
    1475958627  12.614  discharging
    1475958597  12.819  discharging
    1475958567  13.070  discharging
    1475958537  12.016  discharging
```

And here's `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1`:

```
  native-path:          BAT1
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 08 Oct 2016 01:31:27 PM PDT (9 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               empty
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    icon-name:          'battery-empty-symbolic'
```

I'd be happy to just buy a new battery if that's the solution, but I'm hesitant to buy a battery and then find out it's useless…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and bought a new battery after all, and it worked!! So, I guess it was just a bad battery after all!

Comment: Can you set this as solution? It will be shown as fixed then.

Comment: Ah, sorry, first question here, didn't realize that step, thanks

Comment: No problem. Just better so nobody reads your question in order to answer it.